# Firebase Custom Domain 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: firebase-hosting, namecheap

I'm hosting a react app on Firebase. When you navigate to one of the default URL's, the app works fine. I tried using Namecheap for a custom domain and everything is verified and should be working fine, however, I get a `502 Bad Gateway` error when I navigate to my custom URL. My DNS setup is as follows: [image]

Comment: Seems to be working now.

Comment: FYI: DNS servers are public, do not mask the details as those details are required to help you.